# What's the best order for these script tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am getting some errors when opening my page in case I pass by a proxy. When I don't use a proxy, everything works correctly.

The list of imported scripts is as follow:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="js/ng-map.min.js"></script>`

<script src="js/MyJS1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/MyJS2.js"></script>
<script src="js/MyJS3.js"></script>
```

Chrome console shows this:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery 
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

I am not accessing property toLowerCase, but Angular and jQuery do.

What's wrong with my order?

Comment: what proxy are you talking about?

Comment: I used northamericanproxy.com

Comment: not sure how you use that with scripts, do the scripts get loaded when you inspect in browser dev tools network tab?

Comment: Because I am not in the US right now and one of my customers is experiencing a problem nobody in Europe is experiencing. Yes they do get loaded, but probably too late.